# How do I add a webhook to my local magento website in mailchimp without exposing the URL publicly (for SEO reasons)?

Tags: php, magento, mailchimp, webhooks

I am using the `magemonkey` extension from `Ebizmart` and when i save my config in the admin i get the following error:

> Could not add Webhook "http://example.com/monkey/webhook/index/wkey//" for list "Test Mailing List", error code 508, We couldn't connect to the specified the URL. Please double check and try again.

I did some digging and arrived at the conclusion (duh) that `mailchimp` cannot see my local environment so it's unable to add the webhook. Is it possible for me to configure this locally for testing purposes or do I have to wait until the site is live (sounds pretty strange to me)?

UPDATE: I reached out to Mailchimp and got the following response. Seems like they won't add a host entry to recognize my test environment. The only way to accomplish this would be to use a handshake key.

> Thanks for reaching out to MailChimp support. I can certainly understand the concern here and will be happy to help.
>
> Unfortunately, any webhooks being used must be publically available  and there would not be a way to add a host entry in MailChimp so that the URL can be used.
>
> If your testing environement allows for HandShake keys, one options might be to add that on to the url: (can't add more than 2 links)
>
> At MailChimp we definitely appreciate testing and encourage it with our users and I will be sure to pass this feedback along to our developers so that testing in closed environments might be a bit easier. I also wanted to provide a link to our feedback form in case you wanted to leave some feedback for our developers directly: (can't add more than 2 links)
>
> If you have any additional questions or concerns, feel free to reach back out and we will be happy to help.
>
> Thank you,
>
> Mikey

Answer (score 0):

Use https://ngrok.com/, available for all platforms.

It allows you to tunnel requests to your local dev machine. It's very easy to use, just download and run:

```
ngrok http 80
```

Then it'll show you the forwarding URL (where xxx is randomly generated):

```
Forwarding                    https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
```

Use https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io as the begining of your webhook callback URL.

Once it's running, a web interface is available at http://127.0.0.1:4040 that shows metrics and let's you replay requests.